could not find driver (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select top 1 * from [sessions] where [id] = ZvOgLxmPXAuXGtL47cy0GBe2YsyYq9QVkm2pNeBD), Laravel
I'm learning Laravel, I've had more errors with Laravel, one of them that doesn't leave me alone is this, does anyone know how to solve it?
I've even tried using:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function initialization()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}

Results in

could not find driver (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select top 1 * from [sessions] where [id] = ZvOgLxmPXAuXGtL47cy0GBe2YsyYq9QVkm2pNeBD), Laravel



Which DB you are using?Have you properly configured you DB in .env file?

Also you need to install driver.Which version of laravel & PHP you are using?
